# Heroku: does not save session data

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am creating my first flask application. I am deploying an application on heroku from github and it is not working properly. I see the problem in this: I want to save the session ID for the user.

```
@app.before_request
def load_session_id():
session_id = session.get("session_id", None)

if session_id:
    g.session_id = session_id
else:
    g.session_id = generate_session_id()
    session['session_id'] = g.session_id
```

On my local machine this work fine. But heroku resets it every time the user refreshes the page or sends a request. This effect is always observed, not once every 30 minutes, when dino can sleep. I don't understand.

Comment: What is your [`SESSION_TYPE`](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration)?

Comment: I didn't set the session type manually. What does it affect?

Comment: Well, for example if you're doing something in-memory and you are using a WSGI server that spins up multiple processes you'll be rolling the dice each time as to whether you get a process that has the right data. If you're storing on the local filesystem and you have multiple dynos, same thing.

Comment: Me need to think about it. How to do it right for heroku?